# SL4A Scripting on P.C

Tags: android, python, sl4a, ase

Is there a way to write Python scripts for SL4A (ASE) on P.C. and then deploy it on the hardware? I'm new to this and I could write the basic scripts on the device but writing long scripts on phone is tedious. Is there a support for that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ADT could make an easy transfer between PC and android. But you could use wifi keyboard or some app like this, and write in android directly. Also, debuging on PC is a pain, emulated android is slow and error prone for third party like SL4A; the best/fastest is remote control but run script on android. I use a ssh server in android (you find at least 3 free on Play) and Vim from PC and is the fastest and most comfortable way.

Comment: Can't we use eclipse? What about the API Browser that we get on the device? Will we get on P.C. as well?

Comment: Android Studio (Eclipse) has option for testing in emulator/phone (be sure that your phone is connected and usb debug enabled). For python, install pydev in the same eclipse. But autocompletion/suport will be basic. Also, for „real” uploading on phone, you must wrap the script in a app(not big deal, eclipse will upload only changes after first deploy)

Comment: Also can you tell me where exactly do we have to place android.py? In which folder?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible with SL4A app's server support.

Follow the Steps from  [here](http://wiki.android-scripting.googlecode.com/hg/RemoteControl.wiki) .